# Apply if statement inside for loop in Python Jinja Templates

Tags: python, html, if-statement, flask, jinja2

I got this simple HTML template:

```
{% block html_page %}
    {% set counter = 1 %}    
    {% for field in fields %}
        COUNTER: {{ counter }} <br>
        {% set counter = counter+1 %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Where `fields`contains 4 items.

The output is:

```
COUNTER: 1 
COUNTER: 1 
COUNTER: 1 
COUNTER: 1
```

While the output i want should be with the counter increasing:

```
COUNTER: 1 
COUNTER: 2 
COUNTER: 3 
COUNTER: 4
```

The counter assignment is being done INSIDE the for loop, so I don't get why does it keep returning to 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work due to scoping rules in Jinja.

After Jinja 2.10, to solve the scope problem, you can do something like this:

```
{% set count = namespace(a=0) %}
{% for field in fields %}
  {{ count.a }}
  {% set count.a = count.a + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could use loop.index:

```
{% for field in fields %}
  {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did it with the first option. Worked :) Thanks mate !

Comment: This doesn't address using an IF statement within a FOR loop in python-docx / jinja.  Anyone know of a solution for that?  I'm about to ask that as a question and thought this would be my answer, but it doesn't actually address what I need it to so.